# What is the correct order to read the Diablo books series?

Tags: suggested-order, diablo, games

I'm starting to read the [Diablo books series](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Diablo_book_series) and I'm looking for correct order of books to start reading.
**Is there any recommended order for this book series?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This page offers a [publication history](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Diablo_book_series) of the book series
- This page offers an [in-universe chronology](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Chronology_of_Novels) of the book series.

**Per [Diablofans](http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-misc-forums/lore-storyline/69909-f-diablo-books-chronological-order);**

> What is important to note is that **they do not have to be read in this [publication] 
>   order.** The only books that depend on previous books are the Sin War
>   trilogy (which should be read in order) and the Kingdom of Shadow and
>   Moon of the Spider, of which KoS should be read first and MotS should
>   be read second. **All other books can be read in any order** without
>   having any detrimental effect on the plot or story or spoiling
>   anything.